# Django Models - How to tell if an entry is being updated vs a new entry being inserted?

Tags: python, django

For one of my models I am using, there is some conditional logic that occurs, and part of what I need to know is if an entry is being made for the first time, or if it's updating an existing model. My Model is below, I will follow it with an example of what I am needing.

Shipment Model

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    CARRIER_CHOICES = [
        ('GW', 'Greatwide'),
        ('SM', 'Sample'),
    ]
    dateTendered = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    loadNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    masterBolNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    carrier = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, choices=CARRIER_CHOICES, default='GW')
    destinationCity = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    destinationState = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rateLineHaul = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    rateFSC = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    rateExtras = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    rateTotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=0.00)
    loadDelivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    customCarrierRate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deliveryDate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    deliveryTime = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    driverName = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    driverCell = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    rateTotalCarrier = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, default=0)
    shipmentMargin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    shipmentMarginPercentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
    trailer = models.ForeignKey(Trailer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Here are some examples of why I need to differentiate between an update or an insert.

```
Possible Scenarios When Adding a Shipment
    a. Only required fields are entered. Then the following happens
        1a. Calculate rateTotal
        1b. Calculate rateTotalCarrier
        1c. Calculate Shipment Margin
        1d. Calculate Shipment Margin Percentage
    b. Required Fields + customCarrierRate is checked 
        2a. Calculate rateTotal 
        2b. Set rateTotalCarrier = 0.00 
        2c. Don't calculate any Margin 
    c. Required Fields + Value entered in rateTotalCarrier 
        3a. Set customCarrierRate to True
        3b. Calculate rateTotal
        3c. Calculate Shipment Margin
        3d. Calculate Shipment Margin Percentage
    d. Required Fields + Trailer Selected 
        4a. Follow the steps in scenario a
        4b. Save the shipment entry, then find the trailerTrip that matches the trailer Number, and update
            the trailer trip with the shipment load number.

Possible Scenarios When Editing a Shipment
    a. Carrier Rate is changed 
        1a. Set customCarrierRate to True 
        1b. Re-calculate Shipment Margin and Percentage. 
    b. Trailer Number is changed 
        2a. Before saving the entry, find the trailerTrip that matches the old trailer number, and update the trailer
            trip Shipment to NULL 
        2b. Save the shipment entry, then update the corresponding TrailerTrip
    c. Rate is changed 
        3a. Follow steps from scenario a above.
```

Some of the Calculations that are made, are being done by helper functions, these functions are below.

calcRate()

```
# Used by Shipment Model
def calcRate(shipmentId):
    shipment = Shipment.objects.get(id=shipmentId)
    shipment.rateTotal = shipment.rateLineHaul + shipment.rateFSC + shipment.rateExtras
    if shipment.customCarrierRate is False:
        if checkRate(shipment.destinationState) is False:
            shipment.rateTotalCarrier = ((shipment.rateLineHaul * Decimal(
                0.8)) + shipment.rateFSC + shipment.rateExtras) - Decimal(250)
        else:
            rateList = checkRate(shipment.destinationState)
            miles = shipment.rateLineHaul / Decimal(rateList[1])
            linehaul = Decimal(miles) * Decimal(rateList[2])
            shipment.rateTotalCarrier = ((linehaul * Decimal(0.8)) + shipment.rateFSC + shipment.rateExtras) - Decimal(
                250)
    shipment.save()
```

calcShipmentMargin()

```
# Used by Shipment Model
def calcShipmentMargin(shipmentId):
    shipment = Shipment.objects.get(id=shipmentId)
    shipment.shipmentMargin = shipment.rateTotal - shipment.rateTotalCarrier
    shipment.shipmentMarginPercentage = (shipment.shipmentMargin / shipment.rateTotal) * 100
    shipment.save()
```

updateTrailerTrip()

```
# Used by Shipment Model
def updateTrailerTrip(shipmentId, trailer):
    shipment = Shipment.objects.get(id=shipmentId)
    trailerTrip = TrailerTrip.objects.get(trailer=trailer)
    trailerTrip.shipment = shipment
    trailerTrip.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your models, you can overwrite the function save :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    created = self._state.adding is True
    if created:
       # Do your things on created element
    else:
       # Do your things on updated element
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

With this methode, you would need to edit your functions like:

```
# Used by Shipment Model
def calcRate(self):
    self.rateTotal = self.rateLineHaul + self.rateFSC + self.rateExtras
    if self.customCarrierRate is False:
        if checkRate(self.destinationState) is False:
            self.rateTotalCarrier = ((self.rateLineHaul * Decimal(
                0.8)) + self.rateFSC + self.rateExtras) - Decimal(250)
        else:
            rateList = checkRate(self.destinationState)
            miles = self.rateLineHaul / Decimal(rateList[1])
            linehaul = Decimal(miles) * Decimal(rateList[2])
            self.rateTotalCarrier = ((linehaul * Decimal(0.8)) + shipment.rateFSC + shipment.rateExtras) - Decimal(
                250)
```

and save would be

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    created = self._state.adding is True
    if created:
       self.calcRate()
    else:
       # Do your things on updated element
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have a follow up question, just to get a better deeper underlying understanding. For this line of code created = self._state.adding is True. 
Is this the line of code that is telling me "If True: This is a new entry, If False: This is updating an existing entry?

Comment: also one more follow up question, would I then need to make my function a Method rather than a function like I currently have it set?

Comment: "created = self._state.adding is True. Is this the line of code that is telling me "If True: This is a new entry, If False: This is updating an existing entry?" Yes.
"would I then need to make my function a Method rather than a function like I currently have it set? " => yes, like in my answer